# Trying to install ubuntu from usb on gateway with win 8.1

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to install ubuntu with win 8.1, but ubuntu booting from Sandisk 16gb stick doesn't recognize that win 8.1 is already installed and it wants to use all of the existing drive for ubuntu.  It appears to give an option for the user to do a manual partition of HDD or accept
the default of allowing ubuntu to partition and format the entire HDD.  I can't allow it to delete the windows OEM install which already has 4 partitions that win 8.1 is using.  I want to get away from win 8.1 ASAP, but I don't know enough about Linux at this point to be able to do that.  I am usually a fairly quick study and I have read a lot about Linux, but there is still so much that I don't know yet.

I want to give Linux about 80gb plus the 4gb swap partition on my 500gb HDD.  I am currently using only about 55gb of the 500gb drive for win 8.1.

My question is will ubuntu install in the fifth and sixth partitions on the HDD and can I get grub, during the install, to reduce the win 8.1 partition by 84gb for it to use for itself and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to install from usb, first boot to live mode and use gparted to shrink your windows partition. Then run the install and when it wants to use all your disk, it should let you install it to the empty space.

Comment: To: Scott Goodqame, thanks for the reply.  Before I attemptd to install ubuntu, I used "Mini Partition" to shrink the win 8.1 data partition, but did not format it.

Answer (score 0):

From within Windows, defrag, then shrink a partition, then run chkdsk a few times just to be sure Windows is OK.  Then you can install to the free space.  The GPT partitioning is not limited to 4 primary partitions like the old MSDOS partitioning was, so you can freely add your Ubuntu partitions.

---

The Ubuntu install will allow you to add partitions and format them, choose "something else".  I'd use ext4 on the root, swap doesn't need formatting, and make swap 4G, the ram size.

If your Gateway UEFI settings do not allow turning off secure boot without disabling all of UEFI, and you REALLY should look again, since that badly breaks both the UEFI spec and Microsoft's requirements, you have only limited choices. Ubuntu's grub still cannot boot Windows with secure boot on (bug 1091464), but you can still run Windows from the EFI boot menu (a function key at power-up, varies by machine) to select boot device/OS), so that's one choice, leave UEFI/secure boot on, install Ubuntu, and when you want to boot Windows, use the EFI boot to select it.  The other choices are not pretty:

1. Install in different modes and switch modes each time you want to boot the other OS.
2. Reinstall Windows in legacy mode, but the GPT partitioning on the disk will need to be converted back to MSDOS (I think to allow Windows to boot), then install Ubuntu in legacy mode.

Comment: I want to use 85gb for buntu & its swap partition, do I need to make both of these partitions and format them or will buntu do that  while installing.  If I have to partition them, how big should I make the swap partition & what type of format to use Ext4/Ext3 for both?

Comment: My laptop has 4gb ram is gateway NE56R41U 500gb hdd installing from 16gb usb 3.0 Sandisk my CMOS will not allow disabling Secure boot without disabling UEFI, so UEFI with secure boot or bios without.  Please Help me I really don't like mess-Windows and don't know linux enough yet!